# Find all integer values of $x$ such that $x^2 + 13x + 3$ is a perfect integer square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> > Question: Find all integer values of $x$ such that $x^2 + 13x + 3$ is a perfect integer square.

---

What I have attempted;

For  $x^2 + 13x + 3$ to be a perfect integer square let it equal $k^2$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z} $

Hence $$x^2 + 13x + 3 = k^2$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x^2 + 13x + (3-k^2)=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}
 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x={-13\pm\sqrt{13^2-4(1)(3-k^2)} \over 2(1)}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x={-13\pm\sqrt{169-12+4k^2} \over 2}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x={-13\pm\sqrt{157+4k^2} \over 2}$$

We also want $157+4k^2$ to be a perfect square hence

$$ 157 + 4k^2 = n^2 $$

$$ n^2 -4k^2 = 157 $$

$$ (n-2k)(n+2k) = 157 $$

What should I do now?

I have looked at this; [Find all integers $x$ such that $x^2+3x+24$ is a perfect square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128670/find-all-integers-x-such-that-x23x24-is-a-perfect-square)

but I am confused what I should do to continue..

Comment: Almost there. How can you write 157 as the product of two integers?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $x^2+13x+3=(x+\frac{13}{2})^2-\frac{157}{4}$

As you have assumed, let $(x+\frac{13}{2})^2-\frac{157}{4}=k^2$

Hence, by simplifying, we get that $(2x+13)^2-157=4k^2$

Further simplifying by factorisation yields $(2x+13-2k)(2x+13+2k)=157=157\cdot 1$

So, there are only two possibilities:

1. $(2x+13-2k)=157$ and $(2x+13+2k)=1$
2. $(2x+13-2k)=1$ and $(2x+13+2k)=157$

The first one yields $k=-39$ and the second one yields $k=39$.

Can you find $x$ now??

Comment: Why are we allowed to equate (2x+13-2k) to 157 for eg.                                                  What I have learnt that in a quadratic eg: (x-4)(x+5) = 7 , we cannot equate x -4 = 7 and x + 5 = 7?

Comment: The reason is that there $x$ is a real number, but here it is an integer. Also $k$ is an integer. So L.H.S is the product of $2$ integers. But $157$ is prime. So the working is as done.

Comment: Could you link me to a website where this is mentioned , I'm kinda confused understanding this...