# Find ordered positive pairs of integers (x, y) that $x^2y^2-2(x+y)$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Source: [Q1 level Hard test 3 of Violympic National Round 2015-16 (Test 3/c/Q1)](http://violympic.vn/Page_New_Detail.aspx?ID=1413)
 (ended in May 2016).

I have looked for similar questions here on Math.SE, but NOTHING was close to mine.

The competition actually asked for the number of solutions, and the answer was 2, but searching [here on Wolfram|Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28xy%29%5E2-2%28x%2By%29%3Dz%5E2%2C%20x%3E0%2C%20y%3E0&x=0&y=0) shows that there are two solutions $$(x, y) = \{(1, 3), (3, 1)\}$$

Do I have to solve $x^2y^2-2(x+y) = z^2$ (z is an integer) for x or change variables or check possible cases? If it was 1-variable equation like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772218/find-all-integer-values-of-x-such-that-x2-13x-3-is-a-perfect-integer-sq?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128670/find-all-integers-x-such-that-x23x24-is-a-perfect-square?noredirect=1&lq=1) it would simpler.

> Any help will be appreciated. Thank you for stopping by. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $x^2y^2 -2(x+y) = (xy-a)^2$. Then, $a(2xy-a) = 2(x+y)$. This means that $a$ must be even, because $2(x+y)$ is even, and $a$ and  $2xy-a$ have the same parity.

To give you an intuition about our idea, let us think about the following question: What is the difference of squares of consecutive numbers, or consecutive even numbers, or numbers of an arithmetic progression, as they get larger? The answer is quite simple: **As the numbers get larger, the differences get larger.**

Now, suppose you have a *very* large number, and you are to subtract something from it to get a square, as is happening here (with $x^2y^2$ being a very large number, $2(x+y)$ being the subtrahend, and $(xy-a)^2$ being the resulting square). **Whatever  is being subtracted needs to be large enough to be able to get to the  square nearest to the large number, isn't it?** This idea will be key to our proof.

Now, think about this: from a very large number, $x^2y^2$, we are subtracting a very small quantity, $2(x+y)$. Will this quantity be enough to reach the previous square? Note that above I just proved that $a$ has to be even, hence **the largest square smaller than $x^2y^2$ which we can *possibly* reach by subtracting $2(x+y)$ is $(xy-2)^2$**. All other squares which can possibly be reached by subtracting $2(x+y)$ **all have to be smaller than $(xy-2)^2$**. Hence, it is wise to **check the case $a=2$**. That is, we are asking the question: **For what $x$ and $y$ is $2(x+y)$ so large enough that subtracting it from $x^2y^2$ can lead to $(xy-2)^2$?**

For $a=2$, the difference we are looking to overcome is $a(2xy-a) = 2(2xy-2) = 4xy-4$. **We are hence supposed to find all $x$ and $y$ such that $2(x+y)$ is larger than $4xy-4$, for then it will be large enough to result in a perfect square when subtracted,  whether that perfect square be $(xy-2)^2$ or $(xy-4)^2$ or $(xy-72)^2$. We are just looking for whether it is large enough to cross the threshold or not**.

Now, a chain of equalities: $2(x+y) \geq 4xy-4 \iff 2y+4 \geq x(4y-2) \iff x \leq \frac{2y+4}{4y-2} =\frac{y+2}{2y-1} =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{2(2y-1)}$.

Now, we can verify that $x \leq 3$, because  the maximum of the right hand side is $3$, achieved when $y=1$.

**Thus, forget about large values of $a$, for $a=2$ itself, only small values $(x \leq 3)$ are guaranteed to give you a large enough value of $2(x+y)$ such that upon subtraction, it is able to reach the previous square. Which is why we do not need to go for general value of $a$ : if $2(x+y)$ was large enough to reach $(xy-a)^2$, then surely it was also large enough to reach $(xy-2)^2$, wasn't it? But then, that again could happen only when $x=3$! That's why I don't bother about general $a$, and start examining values of $x$!**

Now we can individually verify the solutions:

Take $x=1$. Then $x^2y^2-2(x+y) = y^2-2y-2 = (y-1)^2 - 3$. This a square only when the difference between two squares is three, which happens only with $1^2$ and $2^2$. Hence, $y-1=2$ and $y=3$.

Take $x=2$. Then $x^2y^2-2(x+y) = 4y^2-2y-4$.  Now, I claim that $4y^2-2y-4$ can never be the square of a positive number. For if $4y^2-2y-4=z^2$, then:
$$
y=\frac{1+\sqrt{(2z)^2+17}}{4}
$$

The only two squares differing by $17$ are $9^2=81$ and $8^2=64$. But then $y=\frac{10}{4}$ in this case, hence we do not get an integer value of $y$. Hence there is no solution for $x=2$.

Take $x=3$.Then $x^2y^2-2(x+y) = 9y^2-2y-6 $. Now, I claim that $9y^2-2y-6$ can never be the square of a positive number, except for $y=1$. For if $9y^2-2y-6=z^2$, then:
$$
y=\frac{1+\sqrt{(3z)^2+55}}{9}
$$

All pairs of squares differing by $55$ are the following: $8^2-3^2=55,28^2-27^2=55$. The first case gives $y=\frac{1+8}{9} =1$ and the second case gives $y = \frac{1+28}{9} = \frac{29}{9}$, not an integer. Hence $y=1$ is the only value.

Hence we conclude that $x=1,y=3$ and $x=3,y=1$ are the only permissible values.

Comment: Can you explain further the part when you take a = 2 and explain? I am kind of new to this, so please help!

Comment: @WilliamPhoenix I shall edit my answer, where I shall hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $z$ is the same parity as $xy$, so $z\leq xy-2$.